Break Y-axis while using facet_wrap in ggplot2
I would like to add a break to the Y axis within this figure using the R package ggbreak, more specifically to the bars in the lower panel. However, when I include the funciton scale_y_break() with the desired break values, it messes the figure completely.
This is areproducible example and the figures:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak)

set.seed(2024)
# Create a dataframe to mimic your data structure
df <- data.frame(
  method = rep(rep(c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5"), each = 3),2),
  type = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 15),
  subtype = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 10),
  mean = c(0.56, 0.18, 0.54, 0.59, 0.15, 
           1.47, 0.31, 1.45, 0.76, 0.21,
           1.64, 0.91, 1.89, 1.27, 0.38,
           5.61, 1.41, 0.93, 1.06, 0.42,
           0.45, 0.98, 1.00, 0.81, 4.06,
           1.64, 0.91, 1.89, 1.27, 0.38) * 0.2
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = method, y = mean*100, fill = subtype)) +
  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.7) +
  
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y", strip.position="top") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")


and now if I include the break:
ggplot(df, aes(x = method, y = mean*100, fill = subtype)) +
  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.7) +
  
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y", strip.position="top") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  scale_y_break(c(60, 150))


What is the problem and how can I fix it?

You could add coord_flip() to get horizontal bars. And if you don't want facet titles to be duplicated on each box, add strip.position="right".
ggplot(df, aes(x = method, y = mean*100, fill = subtype)) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.7) +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y", strip.position="right") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  scale_y_break(c(60, 90))


Or use 2 columns for A and B, and remove scales = "free_y":
ggplot(df, aes(x = method, y = mean*100, fill = subtype)) +
  # coord_flip() +
  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.7) +
  
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 2, strip.position="top") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  scale_y_break(c(60, 90))


If you really want to keep one column, you could generate two plots separately and arrange them with ggpubr ggarrange():
df1 = df |> filter(type == "A")
df2 = df |> filter(type == "B")

x1 = ggplot(df1, aes(x = method, y = mean*100, fill = subtype)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.7) +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1, strip.position="top") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(),legend.position="top") +
  scale_y_break(breaks=c(20, 30))

x2 = ggplot(df2, aes(x = method, y = mean*100, fill = subtype)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.7) +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1, strip.position="top") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_y_break(breaks=c(60, 90))

ggpubr::ggarrange(print(x1), print(x2), ncol = 1, align = "v")



But I could not find a way to perfectly align the vertical axes, even with align = "v".

Thanks for your answer. The second suggestion is more similar to what I am looking for but I would like to have both figures in one column, that way I avoid duplicating the X axis. I wonder if what I want is even possible

ok, see the edit for a solution on one column, even if not perfect. When just doing ggarrange(x1, x2, ncol = 1), plots are aligned but the scale breaks are removed, so we have to wrap plots like in print(x1), but it looks like ggbreak breaks the alignment then.
